# Laravel Scheduler: Weekdays and hourlyAt when will it work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scheduler

```
$schedule->command('...')->weekdays()->hourlyAt('55');
```

Which days and at what hours does this command work?

Comment: every 55th minutes hourly, 00:55, 01:55, 02:55, etc... From Monday-Friday

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO ! The community is here to help you if you face some issues, I invite you to read the official doc firstly : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options, it contains all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`weekdays()` means that it will be executed on every day except the weekend, so only on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.

`hourlyAt('55')` means that it will be executed every hour at 55 minutes. So 0:55, 1:55, 2:55, 3:55, ..., 22:55, and 23:55.

These two methods together mean that the given command will be executed every hour at minute 55 on Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday.

Here's a link to the documentation: [Schedule Frequency Options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options)